# JPA (Hibernate) issue saving ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm experiencing a problem: I have an Entity Definition, that has a OneToMany relationship with DefinitionInfo Entities and when I try to load an existing Definition, add a DefinitionInfo to it's infoList collection, saving says it can not find the entity of the DefinitionInfo I just added to the Definition.  To this I say 'DUH!' I am trying to add a new DefintionInfo to the Definition so of course you won't find it!

Here's the code:

```
@Entity(name = "CohortDefinition")
@Table(name="cohort_definition")
@NamedEntityGraph(
    name = "CohortDefinition.withDetail",
    attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode(value = "details", subgraph = "detailsGraph") },
    subgraphs = {@NamedSubgraph(name = "detailsGraph", type = CohortDefinitionDetails.class, attributeNodes = { @NamedAttributeNode(value="expression")})}
)
public class CohortDefinition implements Serializable{

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
...
 @OneToMany(mappedBy="cohortDefinition", fetch= FetchType.LAZY)
  private Set<CohortGenerationInfo> generationInfoList;
...
+ Getters and Setters
```

And the target/dependent object:

```
Entity(name = "CohortGenerationInfo")
@Table(name="cohort_generation_info")
public class CohortGenerationInfo implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public  CohortGenerationInfo()
  {    
  }

  public  CohortGenerationInfo(Integer cohortDefinitionId, Integer sourceId)
  {    
    this.id = new CohortGenerationInfoPK(cohortDefinitionId, sourceId);
  }

  @EmbeddedId
  private CohortGenerationInfoPK id;

  @ManyToOne
  @MapsId("cohortDefinitionId")
  @JoinColumn(name="id")
  private CohortDefinition cohortDefinition;
```

Here is the EmbeddedID class (The Id for the Info consists of the definition's ID + a ID of another entity that represents differetnt types of info.

```
@Embeddable
public class CohortGenerationInfoPK implements Serializable {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public CohortGenerationInfoPK() {
  }

  public CohortGenerationInfoPK(Integer cohortDefinitionId, Integer sourceId) {
    this.cohortDefinitionId = cohortDefinitionId;
    this.sourceId = sourceId;
  }

  @Column(name = "id")
  private Integer cohortDefinitionId;

  @Column(name = "source_id")
  private Integer sourceId;

+ getter/setter
```

Here is what I am doing. This should be so simple, but I just don't understand what is going on:

```
  Source source = this.getSourceRepository().findBySourceKey(sourceKey);
  CohortDefinition currentDefinition = this.cohortDefinitionRepository.findOne(id);
  CohortGenerationInfo info = findBySourceId(currentDefinition.getGenerationInfoList(), source.getSourceId());
  if (info == null)
  {
    info = new CohortGenerationInfo(currentDefinition.getId(), source.getSourceId());
    currentDefinition.getGenerationInfoList().add(info);
  }
  info.setStatus(GenerationStatus.PENDING)
    .setStartTime(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

  this.cohortDefinitionRepository.save(currentDefinition);
```

Here's the Hibernate select just before it blows up:

```
Hibernate: select cohortgene0_.id as id1_4_0_, cohortgene0_.source_id as source_i2_4_0_, cohortgene0_.execution_duration as executio3_4_0_, cohortgene0_.is_valid as is_valid4_4_0_, cohortgene0_.start_time as start_ti5_4_0_, cohortgene0_.status as status6_4_0_, cohortdefi1_.id as id1_2_1_, cohortdefi1_.created_by as created_2_2_1_, cohortdefi1_.created_date as created_3_2_1_, cohortdefi1_.description as descript4_2_1_, cohortdefi1_.expression_type as expressi5_2_1_, cohortdefi1_.modified_by as modified6_2_1_, cohortdefi1_.modified_date as modified7_2_1_, cohortdefi1_.name as name8_2_1_ from cohort_generation_info cohortgene0_ inner join cohort_definition cohortdefi1_ on cohortgene0_.id=cohortdefi1_.id where cohortgene0_.id=? and cohortgene0_.source_id=?
```

Here is the stack trace:

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find org.ohdsi.webapi.cohortdefinition.CohortGenerationInfo with id org.ohdsi.webapi.cohortdefinition.CohortGenerationInfoPK@3
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$JpaEntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:183)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1070)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.internalLoad(SessionImpl.java:989)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolveIdentifier(EntityType.java:716)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:502)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.replace(EntityType.java:366)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replaceElements(CollectionType.java:549)
    at org.hibernate.type.CollectionType.replace(CollectionType.java:690)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.replace(TypeHelper.java:177)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.copyValues(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:407)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.entityIsPersistent(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:219)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:192)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultMergeEventListener.onMerge(DefaultMergeEventListener.java:85)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireMerge(SessionImpl.java:876)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:858)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.merge(SessionImpl.java:863)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.merge(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1196)
```

I stoppped here at the merge part of the stack trace. It appears to be fetchign the existing entity from the DB and mereg it.  The Definition DOES EXIST, it's just a new DefinitionInfo being added.

Does anyone have any thoughts?  I have some limitations on how to structure the database, but I'm hoping this isn't a database structure problem, rather just somethign annoying with JPA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of apparent issues with the code.

1. Since you are expecting to do transitive persistence, i.e., saving CohortDefinition should also save CohortGenerationInfo, you will need to set the cascade property on the OneToMany annotation. For example,

> ```
> @OneToMany(mappedBy="cohortDefinition", fetch= FetchType.LAZY, cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
> ```

2. You have set a bidirectional relationship between CohortDefinition and CohortGenerationInfo. As a best practice, it is better to set the values on both sides of the relationship explicitly rather than relying on the ORM to do it. So the code should do the following (Better to put it in a helper method).

> ```
> currentDefinition.getGenerationInfoList().add(info);
> info.setCohortDefinition(currentDefinition);
> ```

Comment: Wow, you're amazing.  It must have been the cascade = CascadeType.All.  I don't have a info.setCohortDefinition because the CohortDefinitionInfo() takes to its constructor the cohort definition that owns it, and an additional Integer value that is a PK of a lookup value in another repository. I didn't establish a relationship for this other Integer value because it's not important, however both the CohortDefinition.ID and this other entity ID constintues the PK of the CohortDefinitionInfo entity (hence the composite key).  Thank you again!